# Rails 3 - ActiveAdmin - Displaying ActiveRecord object instead of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I currently have a Rails 3.0.10 app and I made two models with simple associations:  has_many, and belongs_to.

After installing the ActiveAdmin plugin and creating the corresponding Ruby resource files, I've noticed some strange behavior.

Below, you can see that "Job File" belongs_to "Ernet Clients".  The associations are all working correctly, however, the display name is appearing as the actual ActiveRecord object instead of the client name.

[image]

This is the show view when under the "Job File" section:

[image]

But, if I go to view the actual client, the correct text appears:

[image]

There must be something going wrong in the "Job File" resource that is causing this, but I can't figure out what it could be.  After googling I found this:  http://groups.google.com/group/activeadmin/browse_thread/thread/2a261e070efa7bae

Within the JobFile.register file I specified the display name with this:

```
filter :ernet_client, :display_name_methods => :display_name
```

This didn't work, though, and I cycled through all of the other available names to no avail.

I looked up ActiveAdmin's dependencies and sass-rails seems to be the only one - but that is if you are using 3.1 and I'm using Rails 3.0.10.

And finally, to be sure that my associations were indeed working, I opened up the Rails console and created a job file:

```
job = JobFile.new
=> #<JobFile hash returned>
job.ernet_client_id = 2
=> 2
job.ernet_client.client_name
=> Target
```

Everything seems to be working as it should.

Anyone have any insight on to how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try defining a `to_s` method on the `ErnetClient` model?

```
def to_s
  display_name
end
```

It looks like this is the method that is being called automatically, as if you did call `to_s` on one of these objects in the console you would get a similar result.

Comment: Ok, I defined a to_s method in the ErnetClient.rb model as you suggested.  It ends up causing an error in the active_admin/resource/index.html.arb file:  undefined local variable or method `display_name' for #<ErnetClient:0x5768058>.  However, I also put the symbol ":display_name" into the method.  This caused the filter dropdowns to literally render ":display_name" for all dropdown choices.

Comment: Well, you don't have a `display_name` method for it. The `to_s` method should return whatever string you want to display for your `ErnetClient` object.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, display_name is a method that already exists in the ActiveAdmin plugin under viewhelpers:  https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/display_helper.rb.  Could there be something that is preventing my app from seeing it?

Comment: The `display_name` method there is provided to your *views*, not to your model. The problem here is that your view is attempting to call `to_s` on your model. Define the `to_s` method, fix the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now: I replaced the display_name method with a string interpolation - #{client_name}.  I didn't think it would work, but I guess since it is in the model it picked up on the property.  Learn something new about rails everyday :)  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You can find the explanation here [Filter select show object instead of object name](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/728).

```
# Active Admin makes educated guesses when displaying objects, 
this is the list of methods it tries calling in order
        setting :display_name_methods, [ :display_name,
                                          :full_name,
                                          :name,
                                          :username,
                                          :login,
                                          :title,
                                          :email,
                                          :to_s ]
```

You may define a `display_name`, `full_name`, or ... (see the list above) ... method in your model.  ActiveAdmin looks for one of those.